# Subscribing to autopublish (for navigation guard)

Tags: meteor, vue.js, url-routing, publish-subscribe, vue-router

How do you make sure that subscription is ready without subscribing to specific publication or subscribeing to autopublish. My page won't load on refresh since data isn't served during compilation, so I'd like to pass subscription to global navigation guard for vue router.

Comment: Meteor.subscribe().ready() perhaps this will magically work

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you are actually trying to do.  How do you plan to get any data if you don't subscribe to anything or enable autopublish?

Comment: I meant subscribe to autopublish or to something like subscribe().ready() global handler. It's what the title says.

Answer (score 0):

So the way I usually handle these issues is by passing the cursors as data through Iron Router and check if the data is available. For example:

```js
Router.route('/', {
    waitOn: [
        function() {
            if (!Meteor.userId()) {
                Router.go('/login');
            }
            return Meteor.subscribe('data');
        }
    ],
    action: function() {
        this.render('template');
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            data: Data.find({})
        };
    }
})
```

```html
<template name="template">
  {{#if data}}
    ...
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Let me know if this works.

Edit:
just noticed the tag for a different router